# Is a regex safe for user supplied filenames - PHP

Tags: php, regex, file, security

I know the golden rule, never trust user supplied filenames.  I want to break that rule though.  Is there anything unsafe about the following scheme?

```
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $id = intval($_GET['id']);

   $sanitized_name = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/','',$name);

   $fp = fopen("/path/to/".$id."/".$sanitized_name.".jpg",'w');
```

If I replace everything that is NOT 0-9 or a-z or A-Z with '' then there's absolutely 0% change anyone can inject a '.' to create their own extension (with the combination of a NULL byte) or traverse a directory.  This seems safe.  I just wanted to run it by SO.

Also since the ID is forced to be an int, anything funky will simply turn into a 0.

Comment: Why in gods name are you HTML-encoding file names?!

Comment: it's just routine sanitization that I copied and pasted.  It shouldn't matter because any HTML characters will get striped anyway.  It's not needed and redundant.  Normal names like 'cat' will stay as 'cat'.  '>cat' will turn into '&gt;cat' which will turn into 'gtcat'.  Doesn't matter since it would have just been stripped.

Comment: "security" isn't something you can just sprinkle on your code like salt on a food and expect it to magically become better/tastier. What are **YOUR** security requirements? Perhaps you're allowing multiple users to upload files and only want them to access their own files. In which case this code is useless, because user A with file `z.txt` can mangle the filename and access `y.txt` which belongs to user B. "oops".

Comment: Don't blindly cargo-cult throw in functions which have nothing to do with the topic. HTML encoding is absolutely worthless here.

Comment: @MarcB This meets my requirements for that.  I would simply checke if($sanitized_name == SOMETHING_ELSE_IN_DIRECTORY) then error else continue

Answer (score 0):

If by secure you mean the user can't force upload in another folder or for another extension, yeah, this is good.

Addtionnaly, for making the filename "more unique", you can add a timestamp `time()` and / or a random number `rand(0, MAX)` in the filename.